# Opencv extraneous bytes for MJPG format

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying save a video from my `usb-webacamera` on `RP4`.
My camera supporting this formats

```sh
[0]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1280x720
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 800x600
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 1920x1080
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x360
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 320x240
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 176x144
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
        Size: Discrete 640x480
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
            Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
```

I'm trying to get `MJPG` data, because `default` `YUYV` has small resolution.

I was able to save a `avi` 1920x1080 video with this code in python

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,1080)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

fourcc = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
fourcd = fourcc
fourcc = fourcc.to_bytes(4, 'little').decode('utf-8')
print("FOURCC=" + str(fourcc))



fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)))

print("FPS=" + str(fps))
print(size)


result = cv2.VideoWriter('filename.avi', fourcd, fps, size)


while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    result.write(img)
```

But during the recording this errors shows up

```sh
Corrupt JPEG data: 2989 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

and my saved video is really fast, it becomes slower when I lower resolution. Does it means SD card is not able to save frames so fast, or the Pi is not able to process compressed frames with that size?

*UPDATE* error won't occurs when I lower resolution

Comment: Why do you require mjpg? That could be an issue on a RPi4 but not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I was doing the same thing with my `Jetson Nano` and  `Gstreamer` my camera was getting 1088px in cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT). Maybe the issues could be this?

Comment: btw. I'm getting the same result executing `opencv` installed from `pip` and also built from source..

Comment: You are not sure why you require MJPG? I see RPi4 has had some issues: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5594.  But that may be resolved.

Comment: Potentially unrelated but I get the same thing on my webcam on Ubuntu 22.04 with opencv-python at the highest resolution w/- MJPG, except the extraneous bytes number is a bit smaller (on every frame).